# Python insert to MySQL : Failed to record Price 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: python, mysql

I have a python code that insert variables "link" and "name" into one table "pricedb" and "avgrate" into the other table

```
#insert product into product table
def insertProduct(link, name):
    try:
        #mySQL instruction to insert to link and name column
        mySqlInsertProduct =  """INSERT INTO products_list (link, name) VALUES (%s, %s) """
        recordProduct = (link, name)

        #executes the instruction and commit
        cursor.execute(mySqlInsertProduct, recordProduct)

        connection.commit()
        print("Product Record inserted, ID:", cursor.lastrowid)

    except mysql.connector.Error as error:
            print("Failed to record Product {}".format(error))



def insertPrice(pricedb, avgrate): #DOESNT WORK
    try:
        mySqlInsertPrice = """INSERT INTO scan_history (price, ratings) VALUES (%s, %s) """
        recordPrice = (pricedb, avgrate)

        cursor.execute(mySqlInsertPrice, recordPrice)

        connection.commit()
        print("Current Price recorded")

    except mysql.connector.Error as error:
            print("Failed to record Price {}".format(error))


#executes the insert functions
insertProduct(link_shrt, product_name)
insertPrice(price_final, ratings)


if (connection.is_connected()):
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
    print("MySQL connection is closed")
```

It can successfully do insertProduct but fails at insertPrice

```
Failed to record Price 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bp40_scraperDB`.`scan_history`, CONSTRAINT `scan_history_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`prod_IDfk`) REFERENCES `products_list` (`prod_IDpk`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

I've tried resetting the AUTO_INCREMENT to begin at 1 and emptied both tables.
The insertProduct ran first and put prod_ID 1 in the primary key already, so I don't know what's wrong with it

Here are my tables
[name and link indexes are just UNIQUE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLdjy.png)

[this is the table with foreign key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SG5q.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary key `prod_IDpk` in the product table also needs to be referenced as the foreign key `prod_IDfk` in the price table `scan_history` otherwise the price doesn't know what it is linking to.

You are getting back the product id at the line

```
print("Product Record inserted, ID:", cursor.lastrowid)

prod_ID = cursor.lastrowid
```

Now pass that to the price insert to make the link

```
mySqlInsertPrice = """INSERT INTO scan_history (prod_IDfk, price, ratings) VALUES (%s, %s) """
recordPrice = (prod_ID, pricedb, avgrate)
```